# Droid: How to get button id from onClick method described in XML?

Tags: android, onclick

Following the dev guide, I can add a method to a button using  in the XML. This calls the 'buttonPress' method in my activity. If I apply the same method to multiple buttons, how can I determine the identity of the button that has been clicked?

Comment: Consider adding a private onClick() to each of them unless you want to get a huge switch of different functionalities over time.

Comment: As the method is to add a character to a string based on each key press, it makes sense to handle that all the same method rather than have 12 virtually identical methods.

Answer (score 72, accepted):

Use `getId()` method. It returnes the `int` id that you can compare to the id from resources.

It is very convenient to use switch statement like this:

```
public void buttonPress(View v) {
    switch (v.getId()) {
        case R.id.button_one:
            // do something
            break;
        case R.id.button_two:
            // do something else
            break;
        case R.id.button_three:
            // i'm lazy, do nothing
            break;
    }
}
```